# video screen capture which supports virtual desktop

Tags: windows

I want to be able to do this:

Create a virtual desktop with http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en and film this desktop then switch back to my normal desktop working while filming goes on.

I can't find a software that can do so until now. Do you know any ?

Answer (score 0):

camtasia studio [link](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/) will do this perfectly as will Adobe captivate [link](http://www.adobe.com/products/captivate/).

I use Camtasia studio and Adobe Captivate depending on project.

A free alternative is camstudio [Camstudi0](http://camstudio.org/)