# capture video in virtual desktop

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, video-capture

I use windows 10 and I need to capture just one virtual desktop and when I move to another desktop, that software should still capture video from the first virtual desktop (like capture video from live show or something).

I use snagIt, but it only captures the current screen. How can I do that?

And I read this question: [video screen capture which supports virtual desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/251584/video-screen-capture-which-supports-virtual-desktop)
But it's not about windows 10 and it's very old question.

Comment: I'd also like to know how to do that, in particular for streaming a particular desktop.